# Mac Rounded Texture Button with custom image on inactive window

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I can see that most apps use Rounded Texture Button for Toolbar commands on macOS. However I can't make those buttons look fully native if I use a custom image (vector or bitmap). The problem is that if the window is inactive, image is still painted the same and not semi-transparent. This works fine if I use the system provided images, so my guess is that it has something to do with the image definition, but I have tried various things (like using Assets or Resources, using vector and bitmap images) and still no success. As said I guess it is something simple, but hard enough that I can't find it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the image as template image. Only then AppKit is able to render the image correctly in every circumstance.